# Trying to get authentication cookie(s) using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, screen-scraping, webclient, httpwebresponse

I have to scrape a table from a secure site and I'm having trouble logging in to the page and retrieving the authentication token and any other associated cookies.  Am I doing something wrong here?

```
public NameValueCollection LoginToDatrose()
{
    var loginUriBuilder = new UriBuilder();
    loginUriBuilder.Host = DatroseHostName;
    loginUriBuilder.Path = BuildURIPath(DatroseBasePath, LOGIN_PAGE);
    loginUriBuilder.Scheme = "https";

    var boundary = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var postData = new NameValueCollection();
    postData.Add("LoginName", DatroseUserName);
    postData.Add("Password", DatrosePassword);

    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData.ToQueryString(false));
    var request = WebRequest.Create(loginUriBuilder.Uri) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    using (var d = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        d.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    var responseCookies = new NameValueCollection();
    foreach (var nvp in response.Cookies.OfType<Cookie>())
    {
        responseCookies.Add(nvp.Name, nvp.Value);
    }

    //using (var responseData = response.GetResponseStream())
    //using (var responseReader = new StreamReader(responseData))
    //{
    //    var theResponse = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
    //    Debug.WriteLine(theResponse);
    //}

    return responseCookies;

}
```

I get no values in the return object.  It does not fail.  The value of `theResponse` (when not commented out) seems to be the HTML of the login page.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, the problem here seems related to the 302 redirect that would occur after the credentials were passed.  The `HttpWebRequest` would automatically follow the 302.

Ultimately, I ended up doing things a little differently.  First, I subclassed the `WebClient` class as follows:

```
public class CookiesAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    private CookieContainer outboundCookies = new CookieContainer();
    private CookieCollection inboundCookies = new CookieCollection();

    public CookieContainer OutboundCookies
    {
        get
        {
            return outboundCookies;
        }
    }
    public CookieCollection InboundCookies
    {
        get
        { 
            return inboundCookies; 
        }
    }

    public bool IgnoreRedirects { get; set; }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = outboundCookies;
            (request as HttpWebRequest).AllowAutoRedirect = !IgnoreRedirects;
        }
        return request;
    }

    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
    {
        WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
        if (response is HttpWebResponse)
        {
            inboundCookies = (response as HttpWebResponse).Cookies ?? inboundCookies;
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

This allowed me to use a `WebClient` class that was cookies-aware as well as one that I could control the redirect.  Then I rewrote my code for logging in as follows:

```
public NameValueCollection LoginToDatrose()
{
    var loginUriBuilder = new UriBuilder();
    loginUriBuilder.Host = DatroseHostName;
    loginUriBuilder.Path = BuildURIPath(DatroseBasePath, LOGIN_PAGE);
    loginUriBuilder.Scheme = "https";

    var postData = new NameValueCollection();
    postData.Add("LoginName", DatroseUserName);
    postData.Add("Password", DatrosePassword);

    var responseCookies = new NameValueCollection();

    using (var client = new CookiesAwareWebClient())
    {
        client.IgnoreRedirects = true;
        var clientResponse = client.UploadValues(loginUriBuilder.Uri, "POST", postData);
        foreach (var nvp in client.InboundCookies.OfType<Cookie>())
        {
            responseCookies.Add(nvp.Name, nvp.Value);
        }
    }

    return responseCookies;
}
```

...and everything worked swimmingly.

Comment: you could have used the httpwebrequest where it has allowredirect property. you can set false;