# WebClient with credentials still not downloading file

Tags: credentials, webclient

I am trying to download files from a website with username/password.  You need to pay for a registered account in order to download files - which we have done.  I am attempting to pass in the username/password and download a file as follows:

```
if (docUrl != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                    this.WebClientInstance.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

                fileData = this.WebClientInstance.DownloadData(docUrl);
                this.WebClientInstance.Dispose();
                isDataDownloaded = true;
            }
```

WebClientInstance is a System.Net.WebClient.  I debugged and verified that it is hitting the line to set credentials.  Instead of downloading the PDF, I end up with an HTML page that prompts me to log in to get access to the file.  I have verified that the username/password is correct.  I use the same credentials to scrape the website with WatiN.

Is there something else that I'm supposed to be doing here?

**UPDATE**

Okay, I've done some sniffing around and found some useful info on this issue.  I still haven't gotten it to work, but I think I'm closer.  First, you need to create a cookie aware WebClient that extends the WebClient class, as follows:

```
public class CookiesAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

    public CookiesAwareWebClient()
    {
        this.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var webRequest = base.GetWebRequest(address);

        if (webRequest is HttpWebRequest)
            (webRequest as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = this.CookieContainer;

        return webRequest;
    }
}
```

Next is to use the WebClient.UploadValues() method to upload the login info to the target website.  The full process of authenticating and downloading the target resource is as follows:

```
using (var webClient = new CookiesAwareWebClient())
                    {
                        var postData = new NameValueCollection()
                        {
                            { "userId", username },
                            { "password", password }
                        };

                        webClient.UploadValues(docUrl, postData);

                        fileData = webClient.DownloadData(docUrl);
                    }
```

I was wrong about the site using forms auth.  It is a JSP website and uses a JSESSIONID.  I have verified that I am getting a cookie back with what appears to be a valid 32-byte JSESSIONID value.

However, when I call WebClient.DownloadData() it is still only returning the redirected login page.  I've tried to fix this by setting the AllowAutoRedirect property on the HttpWebRequest to false, but then it returns 0 bytes.

Is there something else that I need to do so it won't redirect and will take me to the resource once I have authenticated?

Comment: Is the site using HTTP authentication?

Comment: Yeah, it uses SSL.  Thanks for bringing that up.  I should've mentioned it.

Comment: SSL has nothing to do with HTTP authentication.

Comment: Lol.  I believe it is using forms authentication.  It requires cookies.

Comment: Switching to food service? You'll still have to deal with cookies...

Comment: Hyuk hyuk hyuk, I just can't win, huh?

Comment: @dustmouse I'm still getting redirected to the login page. Can you please elaborate on the URL to pass for UploadValues method. Here's my code..client.UploadValues("http://www.xxx.com/cgi/cookie.php", values); var result = client.DownloadData("http://www.xxx.com/cgi/securedownload.php?p=xxx&prodtype=xxx-20140217.TXT.zip");

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Solved. So the problem was between my ears. I was passing in the URL for the secure resource to the .UploadValues() method, knowing that it would redirect to the login page. However, I really needed to pass in the URL from the login form (where it goes upon submitting) - not the login page itself. Once I did that, it worked correctly. I think I'm going to go find a career in food service now.
>
> **LINKS**
>
> There were already a few questions posted on SO that addressed this issue. I just didn't know what I was looking for at first so I didn't see those... Anywhere here are a couple good resources that I came across when working on this issue:
>
> [how to maintaine cookies in between two Url's in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502581/how-to-maintaine-cookies-in-between-two-urls-in-asp-net)
>
> [Trying to get authentication cookie(s) using HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762301/trying-to-get-authentication-cookies-using-httpwebrequest)