# WebClient.DownloadFile stores a file that is too small

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I am trying to download and store an image file in VS2008, .NET Framework 3.5, but the resultant file is too small.

When I navigate to http://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/GetBinary.aspx?Image&ImageID=682367204 in my browser, I am able to download it as a 68k file. However, using the following code, I get a file just under 4k:

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
  webClient.DownloadFile("http://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/GetBinary.aspx?Image&ImageID=682367204", @"D:\\682367204.jpg");
}
```

UPDATE: [WebClient with credentials still not downloading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457487/webclient-with-credentials-still-not-downloading-file) likely describes the source of (and solution to) my problem.

Comment: What does the file contain? Maybe it's just the contents of an error page.

Comment: tried your URL in a browser, doesn't download an image, but rather an .aspx file, asks how to open it...

Comment: @Jonas : you can't get an entire aspx file, just the output of its processing by the ASPX engine. Otherwise this site would have a huge security issue :)

Comment: @M4N: Some small binary with JFIF near the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I guess this is due to **authorization restriction**.

The reason why your code, *Carlos* and myself get a 4K file is because we have not the rights to access the requested file.

I guess you've used a sort of login procedure to access the site with your browser, or are on a trusted network allowing the site to use your NT tokens.

What seems to confirm this hypothesis is that when I change the extension of the GetBinary.aspx file to **jpeg** I obtain a kind of "forbidden" icon.

So you may have to do more work from your code to **authenticate**.

EDIT: using the 'NIX **file** utility with Cygwin gives this :

```
JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
```

So what you get is indeed a JPEG image.

Comment: I'm finding that somehow if I visit [this](http://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/CaseForm.aspx?ViewText&CaseID=760013655&xsl=textonly.xsl&websrc=true) first, then I get the full image file from the original link. I guess I should ask about getting around this authorization restriction in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is something wrong with that url. It is working for me in internet explorer but using google chrome the browser starts downloading **"GetBinary.aspx"** file, maybe that is
the **4ks** file you are getting.